# Unable to generate the right type - securitybaselineauditset

Tags: powershell, object, types

I am trying to do some automation for SQL Server vulnerability assessments using the `invoke-sqlvulnerabilityassessment` component - I am doing this no problem. However, I am stumbling when it comes to doing the baseline audit set - I want to pull this from a table and a database could have 'n' baselines to apply.

I have tried the following code

```
$Vulns = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance localhost -Database SQLAudit -Query "EXEC dbo.Get_Baselines @Server = '$($SERVER)', @Database = '$($db)'"
       $baselineSet = $(foreach($Vuln in $Vulns)
           {
               $Expect = @($Vuln.Expected.split(','))
               New-SqlVulnerabilityAssessmentBaseline -SecurityCheckId $Vuln.VulnID -ExpectedResult $Expect #  $Expected
               #$baselineSet.SecurityCheckBaselines.Add($baseline)
           }) |New-SqlVulnerabilityAssessmentBaselineSet
```

however it is giving me the wrong type (after banging my head for a while I realized it as when I see the contents of $baselineset I get the following output

```
SecurityCheckBaselines
----------------------
{VA1044}              
{VA1287}
```

whereas it should be like this to be able to be used by the invoke

```
SecurityCheckBaselines
----------------------
{VA1234, VA1235}
```

I know about the limitations (longevity) of this as it is only PS 5 - from the documentation - however, is there a way to be able to do what I need to do with this.

Many thanks

Bobby

(and apologies in advance - first question on here)

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone that does stumble onto this, I managed to solve it using the following as it turns out the `New-SqlVulnerabilityAssessmentBaselineSet` will accept an array as an input of `-Baselines`

````
        $Vulns = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance localhost -Database SQLAudit -Query "EXEC dbo.Get_Baselines @Server = '$($SERVER)', @Database = '$($db)'"
        $vulnArray = [System.Collections.Arraylist]@()
        foreach($Vuln in $Vulns)
            {
                
                $Expect = @($Vuln.Expected.split(','))
                $vulnArray.add($(New-SqlVulnerabilityAssessmentBaseline -SecurityCheckId $Vuln.VulnID -ExpectedResult $Expect))
            }
        if($vulnArray.Count > 0){
        $baselineSet = New-SqlVulnerabilityAssessmentBaselineSet -Baselines $vulnArray}```

This now works
````